# How do I insert multiple values from a ListBox into SQL Database

Tags: c#, multi-select

I developed a form that consists of asp.net textboxes and one ListBox control set to “Multiple” that has four companies.
When the submit button is clicked, the form inserts the inputted data into two different tables in a database, and sends an email to the respective company(ies) – all works well
… Except when I attempt to select more than one company – my code will only submit the first company selected, but inserts the first company selected data based on the number of companies selected in the ListBox. For example, if I select two companies, the first company selected is entered twice. 4 times, if I select all four companies – Here is my code/logic. 
Could anyone provide some assistance as to what I am doing wrong? I provided my code below:

/************************************ **aspx:**

```
<p><b>Company Affected:</b><br />
<asp:ListBox 
   ID="lstcompanyAffected" 
   runat="server"
   SelectionMode="Multiple">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Select Company" Value="SelectCompany" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="CompanyI" Value="CompanyI" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="CompanyII" Value="CompanyII" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="CompanyIII" Value="CompanyIII" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="CompanyIV" Value="CompanyIV" />
   </asp:ListBox></p>
```

/******************* **aspx.cs**

```
lstcompanyAffected.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
        foreach (ListItem item in locationAffected.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected) { 
                if ((lstcompanyAffected.SelectedValue.ToString() == "CompanyI"))
                {
                    outageId.Text = "1";
                    txtEmailAddresses.Text = "CompanyI@aol.com";
                }
                else if ((lstcompanyAffected.SelectedValue.ToString() == "CompanyII"))
                {
                    outageId.Text = "2";
                    txtEmailAddresses.Text = "CompanyII@aol.com";
                }
                else if ((lstcompanyAffected.SelectedValue.ToString() == "CompanyIII"))
                {
                    outageId.Text = "3";
                    txtEmailAddresses.Text = "CompanyIII@aol.com";
                }
                else if ((lstcompanyAffected.SelectedValue.ToString() == "CompanyIV"))
                {
                    outageId.Text = "4";
                    txtEmailAddresses.Text = "CompanyIV@aol.com";
                }
         //call insertOutage Function
                InsertOuage();
                //call InsertOutageDetail Function
                InsertOutageDetail();
                //call sendEmail Function
                sendEmail();
            }

        } // end foreach

       panelSendEmail.Visible = false;
       panelMailSent.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your internal conditional statements are based off of "lstcompanyAffected.SelectedValue", which is always the same item each time the for loop repeats. Change the if statements to look at your "item" loop variable instead.

Comment: Ahhh nice catch! He's right your `else if` should be `item.Value == "CompanyX"`

Comment: That makes since, thanks - but, yes, there is a but, I still get the same result as before, here is the code w/ the modification:

Comment: I changed the: lstcompanyAffected.SelectedValue.ToString() == "CompanyX" in my nested conditional statement -following the if(item.Selected)- to reflect: item.Value == "CompanyX" and it still renders the first item selected twice. Any other suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks! ATTN: Evan Phillips

Comment: The conditional statements are working and after creating a label & setting it equal to the item.Text, all that is selected from the ListBox is displayed in the label. Your suggested solution worked, but the company name is still being entered into the database twice, am retracing my code. But, thanks - the selecting Multiple items is working, I just need to find out what th issue with the insert.